# why isn't recv function blocked in blocking mode in python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a problem of socket programming and spend many times on finding error, but haven't found. Could Someone help me, please.

**Server code:**

```
 import socket
 server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 server_socket.bind(("localhost",5001)
 server_socket.listen(10)
 client_socket, address = server_socket.accept() 
 server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 server_socket.bind(("localhost",5001))
 server_socket.listen(10)
 client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
 while True:
     temp = client_socket.recv(100)
     print (len(temp))
     print ("Recv isn't blocked")
 client_socket.close()
```

**Client Code:**

```
import socket
import io

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost",5001))
print("send data finised")
```

When i'm running the program, although client don't send anything to server, but recv() function at server still running, I can't understand why, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

because your client program exit, the socket is close?

Comment: Thank you so much!, I have solved it :). here The error occurs because my client exits before server recv data.